# OAuth 2.0 authentication to Gmail works for accounts with gmail.com domain but not for Google Apps domains

Tags: c#, gmail, imap, google-oauth, google-apps

I have a C# installed application that accesses Gmail via IMAP.  Using traditional IMAP authentication, it works well both for individual Gmail users and for Google Apps users.

I have now added support for OAuth 2.0 authentication using Google's .Net APIs.  This works beautifully for regular Gmail accounts (e.g. someone@gmail.com) but fails for Google Apps accounts that have a different domain.  The user is prompted to login via web browser and accept the access but then the IMAP authentication attempt fails with "Invalid credentials".  Is there something that needs to be done differently for a Google Apps domain?

---

As I first reported in a comment below, I made a minor breakthrough with this.  Originally I was calling GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() with the literal string "user" for the user argument (because this is what I had seen done in many examples). This works for regular Gmail users but I find that, for Google Apps, one must pass the actual email address of the authorizing user.

For a while I thought that this was the whole solution to the problem.  It turns out not to be however.  The trouble is that it now works perfectly in in-house testing but routinely fails in the same old way at the one beta site we have.  I can think of only 4 possible reasons for the failure:  (1) the program is getting an invalid access token, (2) it is corrupting that token somehow, (3) it is doing the XOAUTH authentication wrongly or (4) it is using the token to authenticate an account that the token does not apply for.  I assume Google is unlikely to supply an invalid token so (1) can largely be discounted.  (2) and (3) are always possible but the fact that the code works for our own several Gmail and Google Apps accounts makes them seem unlikely.  And the customer insists that (4) is not the case.  So I remain puzzled.

It was suggested early on that I post some of my code and I am now ready to do that.  Here is the start of the C# function that performs the authentication:

```
private void AuthenticateXOAuth2(string strUsername, string strAccessToken)
{
    uint uStatus = 0;

    // The SASL XOAUTH2 initial client response has the following format:
    //
    //  base64("user=" {User} "^Aauth=Bearer " {Access Token} "^A^A")
    string strInitialClientResponse = "user=" + strUsername + "\x1" + "auth=Bearer " + strAccessToken + "\x1\x1";

    byte[] vbInitialClientResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInitialClientResponse);
    string strBase64InitialClientResponse = System.Convert.ToBase64String(vbInitialClientResponse);

    string strCommand = "AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 " + strBase64InitialClientResponse;

    SendCommand(strCommand);
...
```

---

I am still struggling with this, going up blind alleys and getting even more frustrated. I have to correct one thing I said before: I asserted that the program was working for Google Apps domains in in-house testing. This was an illusion; it actually never has.

Someone told me that I need to use a Service Account to cover domain users.  This seems puzzling to me since my program is in no sense a server but I tried it.  And it did not work the way I tried it -- but I cannot be sure I did it right.  Having some confirmation or negation that using a Service Account is the right strategy would help tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my only hunch is that you're not sending the full email address for the initial client response:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#the_sasl_xoauth2_mechanism

other than that, showing your code may help us in seeing the issue.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea too, thanks.  However I have checked and verified that I am sending the full email address.  I'll poke around a little more and then maybe post some of the code.

Comment: By the way, I believe there is an error in

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#the_sasl_xoauth2_mechanism

The base64 includes a linefeed at the end of the Initial Client Response that should not be there.

Comment: See the description above the base64, "After base64-encoding, this becomes (line breaks inserted for clarity)"

Comment: I believe that you must be misunderstanding that statement.  Or maybe I did not clearly describe the problem I see.  That statement, as I understand it, merely acknowledges that the base64 string is split onto two lines in that document.  If you decode the base64 and look at the last character of the decoded data, you will see a linefeed that is not in the example above and which, if left in, causes the authentication to fail.

Comment: I had to put this project aside for a couple of weeks but I am back working on it now and have figured out what the problem was.  I was calling GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() with the literal string "user" for the user argument (because this is what I had seen done in many examples).  This works for regular Gmail users but I find that, for Google Apps, one must pass the actual email address of the authorizing user.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to check if IMAP/POP is activated in your domain account; In the company i work they restricted this access by security reasons, here's how you should enable it:

Enable IMAP in your Gmail settings

Sign in to Gmail.
Click the  gear in the top right.
Select Settings.
Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
Select Enable IMAP.
Click Save Changes.

Ref: https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018

Comment: Good idea, thanks, but it's not the problem.  When IMAP is not enabled, Gmail is fine enough to send an IMAP response saying, Login as "_user@domain.com_" rejected:  [ALERT] Your account is not enabled for IMAP use. Please visit your Gmail settings page and enable your account for IMAP access.  (Failure)

Comment: Seeing code would really need to be the next step here (even if it's just a small sample to demo the issue). FYI, my project GYB is open source and supports Gmail IMAP OAuth 2.0 authentication. It works with gmail.com and Google Apps accounts succesfully: https://code.google.com/p/got-your-back/source/browse/trunk/gyb.py#179

Comment: Aha, I have just been looking at GYB.  I will look again and see if it shows something I am missing.  Thanks!